# Hugo theme not rendering when built

Tags: hugo

I have a Hugo site using the [hyde-hyde](https://github.com/htr3n/hyde-hyde) theme.

When I serve the site with `hugo serve -D`, I can view the site with the expected theme:

[image: Hyde-hyde theme rendering]

When I build the site to the `public` directory with command `git submodule init && git submodule update && hugo version && hugo` and open the site, the theme markup is missing?

[image: Hyde-hyde theme not rendering]

> Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Note:** I added the theme as a submodule to the themes directory.

Comment: Can you see the theme's submodule in `.gitmodules` file after running the build command? Have you tried with a simple clone?

Comment: Using `file:///` to access webpages is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of config.tohml, you need to specify your real domain name, 
because after the assembly all files will be searched in the root of this address (replace "example.com" with the domain name)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a 1-line command, I would advise to do it step by step.

The problem might be with **git submodule update**. The main common error I face when using this command is that git asks me to commit the complete distribution, and refuse to update the submodule if I have uncommited changes.

To bypass this behavior, you can try the following commands:

```
git submodule update --remote

git submodule update --remote --force
```

Or the problem might be with **hugo**

Try the following command to have more info on what is happening:

```
hugo --log --verbose
```